# Compare Django template variable with template tag

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want to compare the result of `{{ request.get_full_path }}` with `{% url "admin:index" %}`
but i don't know the syntax for that. I tried

```
{% if request.get_full_path == {% url "admin:index" %} %}
{% if request.get_full_path == url "admin:index" %}
```

but in both case i get `TemplateSyntaxError`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this [templatetag snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/545/) to capture the output of any tag.

With the above added to a templatetag lib in one of your apps, and loaded, you can do this:

```
{% captureas admin_url %}{% url "admin:index" %}{% endcaptureas %}
{% if request.get_full_path == admin_url %}
```